# Using Github api to create a file in postman

Tags: github-api

I am new to GitHub API and trying to create a file in my repo using API.
I am using postman to check the API first.

```
PUT Method:

URL:https://api.github.com/repos/KaranS-hexaware/Rapidx_Documentation/contents/text.txt

Body:{
"message":"my commit message",
"content":"bXkgbmV3IGZpbGUgY29udGVudHM="
}

Header
Authorization:Bearer ****************************************************
Content-Type:application/vnd.api+json
```

The response is:

```json
{
"message": "Not Found",
"documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest/reference/repos#create-or-update-file-contents"
}
```

Can I get some input on what I am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

The [create file contents API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/repos/contents#create-or-update-file-contents) example is:

```bash
curl \
  -X PUT \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \ 
  -H "Authorization: token <TOKEN>" \
  https://api.github.com/repos/OWNER/REPO/contents/PATH \
  -d '{"message":"my commit message","committer":{"name":"Monalisa Octocat","email":"octocat@github.com"},"content":"bXkgbmV3IGZpbGUgY29udGVudHM="}'
```

Check if those headers (which are slightly different than yours) make a difference and allow your call to succeed.

Comment: Even if i change the bearer to token in header, its showing same response

Comment: @KaranS The `Accept` header is also slightly different, though.

Comment: OK. Can you adapt the curl example and see if it would work that way?

Comment: When I add Accept in header also its showing the same thing ,"message": "Not Found"

Comment: Will try the curl example